# Custom callback plugin path and copy plugin to /home/user/.ansible

Tags: ansible

Im using ansible callback plugin in some custom path like /var/usr/ansible/plugin.

Everytime I write/modified my plugin. I've to tell my team to copy it from /var/usr/ansible/plugin/ to /home/user/.ansible/plugin/

Is there a way that I dont have to tell all users to copy the plugin if I make any changes from my end

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `callback_plugins` configuration option in your `ansible.cfg` to point to whichever location you want. For example:

```
[defaults]
callback_plugins = /var/usr/ansible/plugin/callback_plugins
```

Comment: that's what I'm using still while running it try to find the plugin under home directory and if latest changes not found, it executed the old plugin